# React tabulator ref becomes null on rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, tabulator

I am using Tabulator with React using the react-tabulator module.

I have used 'ref' for the table component and call actions like downloading data or whatever it may be.

```
import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useReducer, useRef } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import "react-tabulator/lib/styles.css"; // default theme
import "react-tabulator/css/tabulator_midnight.min.css";

import {Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { ReactTabulator, reactFormatter } from "react-tabulator";
import { reducer } from '../common/reducer';
import ChangeStaffCompetency from './ChangeStaffCompetency';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
window.jspdf = jsPDF;

const luxon = require('luxon');
window.DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

// Initial states of StaffCompetency
const initialState = {
    changeStaffCompetencyShow: false,
    staffID: "",
    workflowName: "",
    competentTasks: "",
    competencyEditorRow: null,
};

const StaffCompetency = (props) => {

    // State Handling
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    
    // Reference for the tabulator
    let staffCompetencyTableRef = useRef(null);

    // Action to download workloads data as 'JSON'
    const downloadAsJSON = () => {
        staffCompetencyTableRef.current.download("json", "RTP_Staff_Competencies.json");
    }

    /***
     * ALL OTHER CODE
     */

    return (
        <>
            <h3 className="text-center"> Staff Competency </h3>
            <div>
                <Button variant="dark" onClick={() => downloadAsJSON()}>Download JSON</Button>{' '}
            </div>
            <div style={{clear: 'both'}}></div>
            <br></br>
            <ReactTabulator
                onRef={(r) => (staffCompetencyTableRef = r)}
                columns={staffCompetencyTableCoumns}
                options={staffCompetencyTableOptions}
            />
            <ChangeStaffCompetency
                show={state.changeStaffCompetencyShow}
                onHide={() => dispatch({ type: "changeStaffCompetencyShow", value: false })}
                staffID= {state.staffID}
                workflowName= {state.workflowName}
                competentTasks= {state.competentTasks}
                api={props.api}
                parentCallback = {handleCallback}
            />
        </>
        
    );
}

StaffCompetency.propTypes = {
    api: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default StaffCompetency;
```

`ChangeStaffCompetency` is a react-bootstrap modal component which is used as a custom editor to edit the contents of the cell.

`staffCompetencyTableRef` works fine on the first render but it becomes `null` on rerendering; for instance when I open and close the `ChangeStaffCompetency` modal.

How would I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the type of my `useRef` variable (`staffCompetencyTableRef`) to `const` and used the property of `const` variables to do my work.

```
const StaffCompetency = (props) => {

    // State Handling
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    
    // Reference for the tabulator
    const staffCompetencyTableRef = useRef(null);

    // Action to download workloads data as 'JSON'
    const downloadAsJSON = () => {
        staffCompetencyTableRef.current.download("json", "RTP_Staff_Competencies.json");
    }

    /***
     * ALL OTHER CODE
     */

    return (
        <>
            <h3 className="text-center"> Staff Competency </h3>
            <div>
                <Button variant="dark" onClick={() => downloadAsJSON()}>Download JSON</Button>{' '}
            </div>
            <div style={{clear: 'both'}}></div>
            <br></br>
            <ReactTabulator
                onRef={(r) => (staffCompetencyTableRef.current = r.current)}
                columns={staffCompetencyTableCoumns}
                options={staffCompetencyTableOptions}
            />
            <ChangeStaffCompetency
                show={state.changeStaffCompetencyShow}
                onHide={() => dispatch({ type: "changeStaffCompetencyShow", value: false })}
                staffID= {state.staffID}
                workflowName= {state.workflowName}
                competentTasks= {state.competentTasks}
                api={props.api}
                parentCallback = {handleCallback}
            />
        </>
    );
}
```

It kind of feels like a trick. If anyone knows a better approach, please do comment.

Thanks